# Ghostscript merging ps and pdf files into pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, ps

I am trying to merge some pages of a postscript file 'A' (pages 1 to 3) and all pages of 'B' pdf file and some pages of the same postscript file 'A' (Pages 4 to 5) and all pages of 'C' PDF into one pdf.
Command is executed but same pages from 'A' (Pages 1 to 3) ps file is appended to final output instead of Pages 4 to 5 of 'A'.

Below is my gs command

gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPageList=1-3 ghi-21.ps -sPageList=1-5 bf1ypage4-8.pdf -sPageList=4-5 ghi-21.ps -sPageList=1- bfpage11-37.pdf

Here File 'A' is ghi-21.ps (Total Pages 5)
File 'B' is bf1ypage4-8.pdf (Total Pages 5)
File 'C' is bfpage11-37.pdf (Totao Pages 27)

My Out.pdf should be like File 'A' Pages - 1 to 3 + File 'B' all Pages + File 'A' Pages 4 to 5 + File 'C' all Pages

Comment: tried putting filenames within quotes. But same result.Below is the command gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dBATCH -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts/ -sOutputFile=out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPageList=1-3 "ghi-21.ps" -sPageList=1-5 "bf1ypage4-8.pdf" -sPageList=4-5 "ghi-21.ps" -sPageList=1- "bfpage11-37.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

On looking at the [Manual](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#PDF_switches) there are restrictions on combining inputs.

Apparently according to KenS (2016) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40319742/10802527 we are lucky to be getting any merged output at all !

1. "you cannot process pages out of order" (so no skipping to and fro.) [Ghostscript -sPageList produces stackunderflow error and quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296238/ghostscript-spagelist-produces-stackunderflow-error-and-quits)
2. "PageList overrides FirstPage and/or LastPage"
3. "PDF files enable random access to pages"
4. "PCL and PostScript cannot be handled in ths[sic] way,...*sending multple[sic] files as input on the command line does not reset the PageList between each document,*"

Finally says

"This means you must exercise caution when using this switch, and probably **should not use it at all when processing a mixture of PostScript and PDF files on the same command line.**"